# Delimiter to separate long string

Tags: sql

In Ax Dynamics 365, GL financial dimensions are getting stored in the following manner.

```
41110-GTC-R-West-JD-WJED014-R0101-1410-WJED014-SAL--

11410------R0102-----
```

I want to use delimiter function with ‘-‘ to separate dimensions. Can we create function to separate all the dimensions.

I need the output as follows:

```
11411   GTC   R     West    JD   WJED014   R0101  1410   WJED014   SAL

11410     -     -       -        -       -         R0102    -      -         -
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: second row in your data and its *- charchter* provide problems

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and string functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Would be quite easy in Postgres with `string_to_array()`